# Is there any way to enable unlimited processes/threads in gunicorn to enable sharing to unlimited users?

Tags: python, multithreading, iot

I implement a server in python and serve it with gunicorn.

I have 3 shared sources (urls) with event streams SSE, to be shared to unknown amount of clients.

Is there any way to enable unlimited processes/threads in gunicorn to enable sharing to unlimited users, according to requests ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [the following article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that this command does the job:

`sudo gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:80 MyApp:app --worker-class gevent --timeout 90`

It can serve me as much as possible now.